# Replace substring not doing the work

Tags: java, string

Its should be very simple.

I have this String:

> ins113457MessageResponse  xmlns="httptt://www.ins113457.org/ins113457/"

I wnat to replace part of the string - i use:

```
reponse_str = new
 String(response).replace(" xmlns=\"httptt:////www.ins113457.org//ins113457//\"", "");

reponse_str = 
new String(response).replace(" xmlns=\"httptt://www.ins113457.org/ins113457/\"", "");
```

But both dont work!

Expected output is `ins113457MessageResponse`

What may be the problem?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: This is the expected output: ins113457MessageResponse

Comment: I suggest you try the function with smaller sub-strings

Comment: What is the type and value of the variable `response`?

Comment: Dump every char of the original string and of the substring as integer, and look for differences.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because his code actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
reponse_str = new String(response).replace(" xmlns=\"httptt://www.ins113457.org/ins113457/\"", "");
```

`//` is **not** replaced with `/`
`\\` is replaced with `\`

Answer (score 0):

I tested both.

The first one doesn't work, but that's because all the slashes are there twice, so the `replace` method doesn't find the string. When I remove them, it works fine.

You don't need to double the slashes, because they do nothing in particular in Java strings, but backslashes are used to escape special characters, so you need to espace those.

But I can't tell you about the second one, since it works as expected.